# SImulate runtime object mock K8S

Tags: go, kubernetes

Im using the following function which works.
Now I need to add a unit tests to the below function and I didn't find a simple way how to mock the runtime object of k8s.

**This is the function**

```
import(
"k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime"

)


func GetModified(obj runtime.Object, annotate bool, codec runtime.Encoder) ([]byte, error) {
    var modified []byte
    annotates, err := metadataAccessor.Annotations(obj)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if annotates == nil {
        annotates = map[string]string{}
    }

    original := annotates[corev1.LastAppliedConfigAnnotation]
    delete(annotates, corev1.LastAppliedConfigAnnotation)
    if err := metadataAccessor.SetAnnotations(obj, annotates); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    modified, err = runtime.Encode(codec, obj)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if annotate {
        annotates[corev1.LastAppliedConfigAnnotation] = string(modified)
        if err := metadataAccessor.SetAnnotations(obj, annotates); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        modified, err = runtime.Encode(codec, obj)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }
    annotates[corev1.LastAppliedConfigAnnotation] = original
    if err := metadataAccessor.SetAnnotations(obj, annotates); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return modified, nil
}
```

I want to create a unit test to it but not sure how to simulate the runtime

`obj runtime.Object`
`codec runtime.Encoder`

Any idea how can I **mock** those two values for unit testing?

**This is the unit test**

```
func TestGetModified(t *testing.T) {
    
    
    
    type args struct {
        obj      runtime.Object
        annotate bool
        codec    runtime.Encoder
    }
    // HERE I NEED TO PROVIDE THE RUNTIME OBJECT
    args{
        obj:      nil,
        annotate: false,
        codec:    nil,
    }

    tests := []struct {
        name    string
        args    args
        want    []byte
        wantErr bool
    }{{
        name: "test",
        args: ,
        want:    nil,
        wantErr: false,
    },

    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            got, err := GetModified(tt.args.obj, tt.args.annotate, tt.args.codec)
            if (err != nil) != tt.wantErr {
                t.Errorf("GetModified() error = %v, wantErr %v", err, tt.wantErr)
                return
            }
            if !reflect.DeepEqual(got, tt.want) {
                t.Errorf("GetModified() got = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```